# mysql, make a group by for this case

Tags: mysql

I have this data:

```
column1  |  column2  
____________________
15           2013
16           2012
15           2012 //repeated
15           2012 //repeated
...
...
```

I want to get this result

```
15     2013
16     2013
15     2012  //not repeated
```

Comment: The [first place](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-data-manipulation.html) for you to try to solve your syntax issues.

Answer (score 4):

how about using `DISTINCT`? Since both rows have the same value on column1 and column2.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2
FROM   TableName
```

Comment: @francis: You can get the same result with `SELECT col1, col2 FROM TableName GROUP BY col1, col2;`

Comment: francis I agree with @ypercube the only problem when using `distinct` is when atleast one value of any column is different from the value of the other row of the same column because it is not duplicate anymore. When you say duplicate, both rows have the same values for all columns.